# Algolia - excluding results with specific values

Tags: search, algolia

I'm trying to figure out how to exclude specific records from my search results.

My records look like this:

```
eventId:bcf9e22b-adb1-11e6-b058-0623f336d3b3
name:Event Name
fullAddress:1964 Long Beach Rd, Toronto, ON, Canada
latitude:44.998148000000
longitude:-79.319882400000
eventStartAt:1469948400
objectID:eyJpZCI6ImJjZjllMjJiLWFkYjEtMTFlNi1iMDU4LTA2MjNmMzM2ZDNiMyJ9
```

So while searching for event name I'm trying to exclude certain records that have specific `eventId`.

I'm using Symfony bundle provided by Algolia so my code looks like this:

```php
$results = $this->get('algolia.indexer')->search(
   $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager'),
   'MyBundle:Entity',
   'Random Event Name',
   [
          'numericFilters'      => 'eventStartAt > 1469948000',
          'minWordSizefor1Typo' => 2,
          'filters'             => 'NOT eventId:b2c7a242-e17d-11e6-b058-0623f336d3b3',
   ]
);
```

Which produces request body:

```
{
  "params": "numericFilters=eventStartAt+%3E+1469948000&minWordSizefor1Typo=2&filters=NOT+eventId%3Ab2c7a242-e17d-11e6-b058-0623f336d3b3&query=Random+Event+Name"
}
```

Problem is that `NOT eventId:b2c7a242-e17d-11e6-b058-0623f336d3b3` filter does not seem to be applied at all, and record with `eventId` of `b2c7a242-e17d-11e6-b058-0623f336d3b3` is still present in my results.

Comment: I'm going to answer my own question here.... maybe someone in future will be looking for something similar. `attributesForFaceting` needs to be set in `settings`. In my case `eventId` needed to be added to Attributes for faceting.

Comment: Glad you found the solution and thanks for posting back.